# Extending SupportMapFragment - how to instantiate new fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-2, supportmapfragment

In the documentation for `MapFragment` and `SupportMapFragment` they create a new fragment by calling `newInstance()` instead of using `new SupportMapFragment()`.

My app project extends `SupportMapFragment`, and I tried to call `MyMapFragment.newInstance()` on my fragment class, resulting in the map showing up as expected but none of my overridden methods such as `onCreateView()` and `onActivityCreated()` were being called. Took me a while before I tried instantiating my fragment by using `new MyMapFragment()` instead - and voíla, my overridden methods started getting called!

I didn't override `newInstance()` in my class, and in hindsight it's obvious that `newInstance()` returns an instance of `SupportMapFragment`, not an instance of my extended class (duh!).

But my question is - why **is** there a `newInstance()` method and why does the documentation use it, when it seems to work just as well using `new SupportMapFragment()`? What's the difference of using one or the other? I haven't been able to find the source code for SupportMapFragment, so...

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I believe the `newInstance` method is just a static factory method for the empty constructor so has no effect (though without the source code available we cannot know for sure), i.e. it is probably something like:

```
public static SupportMapFragment newInstance() {
    return new SupportMapFragment();
}
```

So why does it exist?

- For consistency with the other `newInstance(GoogleMap)` method most likely
- In theory the method could return a sub-class of `SupportMapFragment`, perhaps one optimised for the device or platform
- In case any arguments need to be set (perhaps now or in the future)

Because of the last point, it is generally a good practice to always use static factories when creating fragments, in the future it could be modified to:

```
public static SupportMapFragment newInstance() {
    SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putBoolean("secretOptionNotEnabledWithNormalConstructor", true);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Comment: So should one make use of the superclass' newInstance() when extending it? If there is indeed something special going on inside SupportMapFragment.newInstance(), wouldn't it be best to use that as the "constructor" for my subclass? How would I do that exactly?

Comment: You can't make use of the newInstance() when subclassing it because static methods cannot be overridden (static methods are really like global functions, the class name just provides some scope)

Comment: Alright, had a feeling that was the case. (but it's 1 am here so I couldn't really wrap my head around it right now :) Thanks.